Unique Representation of Integrable Functions on a Sub-$\sigma$-Algebra Without Radon-Nikodym
I am working on a problem in measure theory involving $\sigma$-finite measure spaces and sub-$\sigma$-algebras. I need to prove the following without using the Radon-Nikodym theorem. This problem is based on Problem 9.13 from the book by Fava-Zó.
Given a $\sigma$-finite measure space $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ and a $\sigma$-finite sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma_0$, prove that for every $f \in L^1(X, \Sigma, \mu)$, there exists a unique function $g \in L^1(X, \Sigma_0, \mu)$ such that for all $E \in \Sigma_0$,
$$
\int_E f \, d\mu = \int_E g \, d\mu.
$$
$\textbf{Hint:}$
First, assume that $\mu(X) < \infty$, and use the Riesz representation theorem for the functional on $L^2(\Sigma_0)$ defined by
$$
\ell(g) = \int_X f g \, d\mu.
$$
$\textbf{My Attempt:}$
If the Radon-Nikodym theorem could be used, the problem would be resolved quickly (like this). However, I am asked to find a proof without it.
We will start by proving the case where $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ is a finite measure space, meaning $\mu(X) < \infty$.
For a function $f \in L^1(X, \Sigma, \mu)$, we define a linear functional $T_f$ on $L^2(X, \Sigma_0, \mu)$ as follows:
$$
T_f(h) = \int_X f \cdot h \, d\mu
$$
for all $h \in L^2(X, \Sigma_0, \mu)$.
It is straightforward to see that $T_f$ is linear. However, I am struggling to prove that $T_f$ is bounded. I attempted to use Hölder's inequality:
$$
|T_f(h)| = \left|\int_X f \cdot h \, d\mu\right| \leq \|f\|_{L^1} \|h\|_{L^\infty}
$$
But I am not sure if this is the correct approach or if I am missing something. Any insights or guidance on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
EDIT 1. Additionally, I am also looking for a possible counterexample. However, such a counterexample would not apply to the entire problem since it can be proven using the Radon-Nikodym theorem.

(for anyone interested on getting more information on this, the function $g$ is often called the conditional expectation of $f$ on $\Sigma_0$, denoted $g=E(f\,|\,\Sigma_0)$.
Your approach is suspect, since it doesn't use that $\mu(X)<\infty$. The functional $T_f$ is unlikely to be bounded if $f$ is not in $L^2$.
What you can get from $\mu(X)<\infty$ is that $L^2(X)$ is dense in $L^1(X)$.
Given $f\in L^1(X,\Sigma)$, there exists $\{f_n\}\subset L^2(X,\Sigma)$ such that $\|f-f_n\|_1\to0$. For each $n$, consider on $L^2(X,\Sigma_0)$ the linear functional $h\longmapsto\int_Xf_n\,h\,d\mu$. By the Riesz Representation Theorem there exists $g_n\in L^2(X,\Sigma_0)$ such that
$$
\int_Xg_n\,h\,d\mu=\int_X f_n\,h\,d\mu. 
$$
As $\mu(X)<\infty$, we have $L^\infty(X)\subset L^2(X)$. If $h\in L^\infty(X)$ is the function such that $h(g_n-g_m)=|g_n-g_m|$, then $\|h\|_\infty=1$ and
$$
\|g_n-g_m\|_1=\int_X(g_n-g_m)h\,d\mu=\int_X(f_n-f_m)h\,d\mu\leq\|f_n-f_m\|_1.
$$
Hence $\{g_n\}\subset L^1(X,\Sigma_0)$ is Cauchy and $g=\lim_ng_n$ exists. Now Dominated Convergence gives
$$
\int_X g\,h\,d\mu=\int_Xf\,h\,d\mu
$$
for all $h\in L^\infty(X)$. In particular,
$$
\int_Eg\,d\mu=\int_Ef\,d\mu
$$
for all $E\in\Sigma_0$.

I was thinking the same thing. However, I'm surprised that the problem provides this hint and yet it seems difficult to bound the operator in order to use the Riesz representation theorem. Maybe by approximating $f$ with functions $f_n \in L^2(X, \Sigma, \mu)$, since $L^2$ is dense in $L^1$?

Yes, that's why I mentioned the density.

Since $L^2(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ is dense in $L^1(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ under the finite measure hypothesis, there exists a sequence ${f_n} \subset L^2(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ such that $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$. For each $f_n$, we define the functional
$$
T_{f_n}(h) = \int_X f_n \cdot h , d\mu,
$$
which is linear and bounded on $L^2(X, \Sigma_0, \mu)$. We want to show $T_{f_n}(h) \to T_f(h)$. However, applying Hölder's inequality, we get
$$
\left|\int_X (f - f_n) \cdot h , d\mu \right| \leq |f - f_n|{L^1} |h|{L^\infty},
$$
encountering the same issue.

There's no issue there. In any case, I have added more details to the answer.
